# CMake syntax highlighting on stderr from c++ compiler

Tags: c++, cmake

I was wondering how to turn on syntax highlighting on `c++ compiler stderr` from `cmake`.

For example:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT some_output
        COMMAND ${CXX} some_file.cpp -o some_output
)
```

when failing at compiling it outputs the error message in my terminal **unhighlighted**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly related, why aren't you compiling through `add_executable()` / `add_library()`? Those usually highlight the output just fine, and using `add_custom_command()` strikes me as... strange?

Comment: Because I cross-compile and I do not wanna use this `cross-compilation toolchain` from cmake.

Comment: Which also works fine for me (using MinGW / [MXE](http://mxe.cc/) to compile Windows binaries on Linux)... I don't think you get much control over the output from `add_custom_command()`. There is an option `USES_TERMINAL`, but I am not sure it will do anything for you.

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks for your answer:) I expected it already... I might file an issue and see what the cmake people say about it.

Comment: `execute_process()` gives you the ability to capture stdout / stderr in different variables. But that's still mis-using commands; be prepared for the CMake people telling you to use the tool as it was designed (i.e. `add_library()` and the cross-compilation toolchain option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from **cmake issues**:

Basically in `auto` mode GCC calls `isatty(3)` which is always false when being called via CMake.

Pass `-fdiagnostics-color=always` to the compiler.